# Recreate cursorloader for fragment

Tags: android, reload, android-cursorloader, fragmentpageradapter

In app activity I have `ViewPager` attached to `FragmentPagerAdapter` which have three items all of them have list views attached to cursor loaders.

```
public static class TaskListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {          
    public TaskListFragment() {     
    }
    protected static final String excludeCompletedArg = "excludeCompleted";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...         
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(filter, cursorArgs, this);
...         
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
                Uri.parse("content://someurl"), 
                null, 
                null, 
                new String[] { Integer.toString(arg0), arg1.getString(TaskListFragment.excludeCompletedArg) }, 
                null);
    }
}
```

But which way I can force to reload cursor with new bundle argument? For an example I handle `onTabReselected` of main activity

```
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    LoaderManager loaderManager = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition()).getLoaderManager();      
}
```

thows exception.

I don't want to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you whant to reload cursor in some situations. In order to do that you may use restartLoader method. In your method onTabReselected you just need to restart loader of given id and pass in the argument to recreate.

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(id, args, this);
```

It works just like initLoader but always enforces reload. Your onCreateLoader pattern should be:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
   if (loaderId == ARBITRARY_LOADER_ID) {
     // create and return Cursor Loader
   }
}
```

Refer:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: I didn't know that LoadManager is instance-independent.
`getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderId, args, (android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(loaderId))` throws exception Fragment TaskListFragment{********} not attached to Activity

Comment: You may try invoking 

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(id, args, getActivity());
in onResume() of each fragment.

Comment: `onResume` partially works. There are some problems with it. When were relesect current tab `onResume` will not invoke. And I don't need to reload cursor each time when `onResume` was invoked, so I need in `onTabReselected` set some flag for certain `Fragment` and force `onResume` for this `Fragment`. It is so complicated, so I have decided to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static class TaskListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
        private static Hashtable<Integer, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>> loadedFragments = null;

    public static void ReloadCursor(int fragmentIndex) {
        Bundle cursorArgs = new Bundle();
        cursorArgs.putString("someArg", "someArgNewValue");

        ((Fragment) loadedFragments.get(fragmentIndex)).getLoaderManager().restartLoader(fragmentIndex, cursorArgs, loadedFragments.get(fragmentIndex));
    }

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        if (loadedFragments == null) {
            loadedFragments = new Hashtable();
        }

        Bundle cursorArgs = new Bundle();
        cursorArgs.putString("someArg", "someArgValue");

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(fragmentIndex, cursorArgs, this);

        loadedFragments.put(fragmentIndex, this);

                    ...
    }
}
```

Then invoke `TaskListFragment.ReloadCursor(int fragmentIndex)` from parent activity, for example, from `onTabReselected`. It works.

Any suggestions for more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it,
1) if the Loader is on an Activity, just restart loader.
e.g getLoaderManager().restartLoader(id,bundle,callback);

2) if the Loader is on a Fragment, restart the fragment from its host Activity,
by creating an interface on the fragment to send it details to the Activity and restart fragment if details is true.